# How to join a data.table with multiple columns and multiple values

Tags: r, performance, data.table, binary-search

An example case is here:

```
DT = data.table(x=1:4, y=6:9, z=3:6)
setkey(DT, x, y)
```

Join columns have multiple values:

```
xc = c(1, 2, 4)
yc = c(6, 9)
DT[J(xc, yc), nomatch=0]
   x y z
1: 1 6 3
```

This use of `J()` returns only single row. Actually, I want to join as `%in%` operator.

```
DT[x %in% xc & y %in% yc]
   x y z
1: 1 6 3
2: 4 9 6
```

But using `%in%` operator makes the search a vector scan which is very slow compared to binary search. In order to have binary search, I build every possible combination of join values:

```
xc2 = rep(xc, length(yc))
yc2 = unlist(lapply(yc, rep, length(xc)))
DT[J(xc2, yc2), nomatch=0]
   x y z
1: 1 6 3
2: 4 9 6
```

But building xc2, yc2 in this way makes code difficult to read. Is there a better way to have the speed of binary search and the simplicity of `%in%` operator in this case?

Comment: I think you're looking for *cross join* - which is the function `CJ`. Try `DT[CJ(xc,yc), nomatch=0L]`. Feel free to post this as the answer (if correct) and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to remove this question from DT tag open questions.
Code from Arun's comment `DT[CJ(xc,yc), nomatch=0L]` will do the job.